# Generating a BCH address offline

Tags: bitcoin-cash, address-generation, offline

To generate offline BTC addresses, I use the bitcoin-core app from bitcoincore.org.  What is the BCH equivalent of this?

Is it the [bitcoin-unlimited](https://www.bitcoinunlimited.info/download) app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about Bitcoin.

Comment: I have made it clear that this post is about bitcoin-cash as tagged.  It is not about bitcoin.  So to say that this post is about bitcoin makes no sense when I never claimed it to be about bitcoin.  I also made sure to use the stackexchange provided tag called bitcoin-cash to talk about bitcoin-cash.  If bitcoin-cash questions are prohibited on this site, why does the bitcoin-cash tag exist?  I only posted about bitcoin-cash here when I noticed that a bitcoin-cash tag exists which led me to believe that bitcoin-cash talk is fine.

Comment: This community has explicitly set its topic scope to include questions about other cryptocurrencies. I'm therefore reopening this question.

Comment: @G.Maxwell: If you want to have a discussion to change the scope of this website, please take it to [meta](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, bitcoin-unlimited lets you create BCH addresses offline.

Comment: Same to you, @oshirowanen: please focus on the topic of the site in question and answer posts. To discuss the site, its scope, and policies, please use [meta].

Comment: @Murch, Done: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/why-so-hostile-towards-all-cryptocurrencies-except-bitcoin.  Thanks.